# How to calculate NPV with irregular data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help me with irregular NPV calculation in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam. Please update your question to include your attempted formula and the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try these? Where b2:g2 is the cashflow and b1:g1 is the date

`=XNPV(0.12,B2:G2,B1:G1)`

'=XIRR(B2:G2,B1:G1,12)'